# Is the Lemma4.5 in the Plonk paper correctly described？

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, zero-knowledge

In lemma4.5, of [PlonK: Permutations over Lagrange-bases for
Oecumenical Noninteractive arguments of
Knowledge](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953.pdf)
they claim that we can construct a polynomial protocol $P^*$ with an $S$-ranged polynomial protocol $P$. However, in my opinion, I think it constructed $P$ using $P^*$ in the proof.

Specifically, in the last step of the construction, the verifier queries the identity of a polynomial(not in a range $S$),  so it is invoking a polynomial protocol to construct an S-ranged polynomial protocol, not the opposite.
In the construction of the proof of lemma4.5, I think the prover can prove that $F_i(x)$ equals $0$ in range $S$.

Can anyone explain if my thoughts are right? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a link and a mathematical description of your exact question.

Comment: Why do you say verifier queries "not in Range S"? The final step is to prove that the polynomial is 0 in the subgroup.

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953.pdf

Comment: The verifier queries that the polynomial equals 0 in any situation to ensure F_i(x) is 0 in the subgroup.

Comment: thank @kelalaka for editing this question！

Comment: i still can't understand it, could anyone explain more specifically?